# How to extract numbers from mixed dataframe column and replace with numbers only (inplace)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following toy dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['1a',np.nan,'10a','100b','0b'],
                   })
df

    A
0   1a
1   NaN
2   10a
3   100b
4   0b
```

I want to remove all the characters/strings and extract the numbers in A column.
There is an inplace=True method, but how can extract the numbers and replace them inplace?

I want to get:

```
    A
0   1
1   NaN
2   10
3   100
4   0
```

Here is how I am doing it now:

```
df.A = df.A.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Comment: I guess you already answered your question with that last line; do you strictly need `inplace=True`? It [isn't](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529) superior, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.extract` as the name suggested, doesn't replace, only extracts. Try:

```
df['A'].replace('(\D.*)','',inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     A
0    1
1  NaN
2   10
3  100
4    0
```

More info on the regex pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/kBb0D0/1). Basically:

1. `\D` matches any non-digit character
2. `.*` matches all the characters that following `\D`.

So the pattern replaces everything from the first non-digit character with the empty string `''`.

Comment: Dear Quang, please be so kind and explain the regex

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. Simple explanation would be: using `replace` function of pandas, where I am making regex true, then in regex place its mentioned that to replace anything apart from digits with NULL.

```
df['A'].replace('([^0-9]*)','', regex=True)
```